# I m using python 2.7. Facing issue with 'END' keyword

Tags: python-2.7

The following print statement was executed-

```
print ('Hello',end='\t')
```

but found following error:

```
Output: 
       File "Control_Statements.py", line 124
    print ('Hello',end='\t')
                      ^
SyntaxError:
    invalid syntax
    -
```

Comment: There may be an issue with the previous line (line 123)

Comment: I m executing only this statement.No additional statements present in the program.

Comment: Then how does the error occur on line 124? Where are the other 123 lines?

Comment: rest all lines are n comment section

Comment: The issue in that case is probably that the `end` keyword doesn't work in Python 2.7. In Python, `print` is a statement, not a function, so your `print` syntax is wrong. Try using Python 3 or using the correct Python 2 `print` syntax

Comment: will try this.. thanks